# how to use googlecharts API: DataTable.toJSON()

Tags: macos

all

I want to use php to get data from mySQL database, then use googe charts to draw a chart. I used json_encode() to convert my query result table to JSON, but it does not work. It returned, the table has no columns. I noticed there is toJSON() function in Google charts API, but there is no detailed information. Anyone knows how to use this function? thanks